# Can TO_DATE function return a TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, to-date

Can, in any form, `to_date` function return a `timestamp`?

**Example** :

I have the following input: **`'2019-05-31 13:15:25.000000000'`**

I want to have **`'2019-05-31 13:15:25'`** as a result using `to_date` and not `to_timestamp`.

**I tried** :

```
select to_date(
               substr('2019-05-31 13:15:25.000000000', 1, 19), 
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
              ) 
  from dual;
```

But it returns:

> ```
> 31/05/2019
> ```

Comment: Do you just want the time to display in your return output? Because it IS still there, it's just not being displayed.

Comment: Yes. If possible I want it to be visible

Comment: If you got `'2019-05-31 13:15:25.000000000'` as a string, you can simply use the SUBSTR with TO_DATE. If it's a TIMESTAMP apply TO_CHAR.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the fractional seconds of a timestamp `cast(timestampcol as date)`

Comment: When I execute your test statement in PL/SQL Developer it returns `31-May-2019 13:15:25`. I have the default DATE format set to `DD-MMM-YYYY` and the default TIME format set to `HH:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_date` returns a `date`. If you need a `timestamp`, you should use `to_timestamp`.

Comment: But an Oracle DATE still has a TIME part, just doesn't display by default :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to display a timestamp value as so, then keep style1, otherwise if you wish to convert to a truncated datetime type value, then use style2 as in this :

```
with t( ts ) as
(
 select systimestamp from dual
)
select to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as style1,
       to_timestamp(
                    to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                   ) as style2,
       ts as original
  from t;

STYLE1              STYLE2                           ORIGINAL
------------------- -------------------------------  -----------------------------------
2019-07-11 17:03:15 11-JUL-19 05.03.15.000000000 PM  11-JUL-19 05.03.15.298742 PM +01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE` is used to read the date format you have as in your query it reads as 
 `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`

```
     to_date(substr('2019-05-31 
    13:15:25.000000000', 1, 19), 'YYYY-. 
     MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

and gives the default date format not default timestamp format of your database in order to manipulate the date you can use `TO_CHAR(to_date(substr('2019-05-31 
        13:15:25.000000000', 1, 19), 'YYYY-. 
         MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),"your_format") 
           from dual`

or use to_timestamp(...)

Answer (score 0):

You convert between `date` and `timestamp` values using [`cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CAST.html).

However I am not sure what your starting datatype is, or why you need `to_date()` specifically to return a timestamp.